# How do you declare an object in C++?

Tags: c++, object, forward-declaration

Super simple: How do you declare a (non-pointer) object in C++?

I tried:

```
Object obj;
```

But the C++ compiler thinks that this is a call to the object's default constructor. Is it even possible to forward declare objects in C++?

EDIT: I don't think anyone is understanding my question. Why is it that you can declare `int x;` and `Object* objptr;`, but not `Object obj;`? I need this because a struct outside of main has to recognize the Object (so it needs to be *declared* outside of main, before the struct), but if the object isn't initialized inside of main then the library I'm using won't function properly.

Comment: Well, yeah, it has to be constructed so you can use it, unless it's a fundamental type. This isn't Java or C#. If you're 100% sure you need an optional object, use `boost::optional`.

Comment: `extern Object obj;` Works for any type. Don't forget the proper definition in exactly one compilation unit, or you get an undefined reference error.

Comment: @user3553031: Of course you can.

Comment: @Deduplicator If it is not instantiated it is not an object.

Comment: @user3553031: `extern` works in the same way for objects and functions.

Comment: @juanchopanza: As I said, a later definition (which does the instantiation) is mandatory.

Comment: @CoffeeMaker: apparently you have some misconception, but it's unclear what. are you thinking of C's tentative declarations? C++ doesn't have them.

Comment: Ok, getting closer. Please give us a real example of what you need to do. Which library and object is this? What is the structure (or an example of one) that needs it?

Comment: `int x;` **is not only a declaration**. It is a definition.

Comment: @nhgrif: The OP says "Why is it that you can declare int x; and Object* objptr;, but not Object obj;?" -- But whether or not you can do `Object obj;` depends upon the definition of `Object`. Since the definition of `Object` is not provided, the question is unclear.

Comment: Okay, so why did it take so long for that explanation to be offered?  I'm not a C++ expert, and clearly the OP isn't either, but if his question is unclear, someone should explain why so he has an opportunity to provide whatever clarity he can.

Comment: Write *functions* to access your objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate objects of incomplete classes (i.e. classes that are forward declared only). However, you're able to define pointers and references to them:

```
class Object;

Object *myObject;

class Object {
    int someMember;
};
```

C# and Java use references by default, something that doesn't apply to C++.

Answer (score 0):

there can be any number of

```
extern Type var; // declaration
```

and should be exactly one

```
Type var; // definition & declaration
```

`Type` has be be defined in the translation-unit either way, prior to the declaration